# Placing a label based on a point's location within a polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, labeling, position, spatial-relationship

I have a polygon dataset and a point data set with occupants. I need to label the occupants of the house within the polygon and need the label to show up on the side associated with its polygon.

Simple breakdown - if the house is on the right extremity of the plot, the label will need to be on the left so it visually looks like it belongs to that plot.  If the house is on the left extremity, I need the label to show up on the right of the point.

How can I make this dynamic? I can set the zones in maplex but that won't take into account the points placement within the polygon. There are a lot of points to manage so i don't want to convert anything/place them manually ideally.

edit: Using ArcGIS 10.2.1

Comment: Could you please update your post to include which version of arcgis you are using?

Comment: And a screenshot as an example would be helpful.

Comment: You can use label weights to avoid overprinting points, it's on the labeling toolbar, make the polygon weight 0, the border 10 and the building 100 and maplex will avoid putting the label over the building but will not guarantee that the label appears within the polygon. In this case I would transfer the value to the polygons (spatial join) and label them instead of the points, this would give you more freedom to move. Like ian said I'd really need to see a screen shot to be more specific.

Comment: If there is 1 point per patcel and parcel is small, why not label parcel itself. More elegant solution would be to create a new point near beginning of line from address point to parcel centre. Even nicer to have a centre computed from largest inscribed circle